# Pushnotification for ios via PHP Server

Tags: php, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I like to implement in my IOS application. I have already created  certificate for push notification and `pushkey.pem` when I have implement it from my mac I have received push notification in the device but when i try to implement it from my server I am getting the following error I don't know how to over come this issue please suggest me some idea to solve this issue

**Errors**

**1)**`Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)`

**2)**`Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource`

**3)**`Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource`

Comment: Can you hit that address with a curl request in the command line (on your server)?

Comment: Can you submit the code where you generate the payload and the binary. Should look something like this: $body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'Hello world!', 'badge' => 1);
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . json_encode($body);
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

Answer (score 6):

Hi friend please refer the tutorial
  http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1
They explained all about push notification and how to implement.

You also get the iOS and PHP sample code.

Comment: I have refer this code only while using this only i am getting the above errors

Comment: It's your certificate issue.You create the certificate properly.I think then your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

see php-apn extension to PHP

> Apn is a PHP extension to introduce simple yet powerful interface for
>   sending push notifications to iOS  and OS X devices from within your
>   PHP code

http://pecl.php.net/package/apn

Answer (score 0):

***PHP CODE.. FOR IOS PUSH NOTIFICATION***

to send push notification call this function and pass device id and message you send in pushnotificaion...

```
function pushnotification_ios($device_token, $message){

        $passphrase = "Your_PEM_File_Password_Here";

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', YOUR_PEM_FILE_PATH_HERE);
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    // use this when you in sandbox mode..
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    // use this when you in development mode..
    //  $fp = stream_socket_client(
    //  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    //$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        $body['aps'] = array(
            'badge' => $badge,
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'content-available' => '1'
        );
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($body);
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $device_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));  //echo "<pre>"; print_R($result);
        /*
        if (!$result){
            $data = array(
                'Message' => 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL
                );
            }  else {
        $data = array(
                'Message' => 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL
                );
        } //echo "<pre>"; print_R($result); */

        fclose($fp);
    return $result;
    }
```